How can I solve my error when I try to run code?
def is_prime(n):
    # Write your function code here...
    if 2 <= n and n < 1000 :
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n % i == 0:
              return False
            else:
              return True
        
        
print(is_prime(975))

why print(is_prime(975)) is true prima and n = 2 is None. I need answer 975 is false and n = 2 is true

Use code formatting, son! Always remember to read help page and FAQ about how to write a well-accepted question! People who answers aren't some paid workers, questioner doing the answerer's flavor is the minimum questioner can do!

Do the answers to this question help at all?

The example posted by quamrana is good in that it has a catch-all return True and only return False within the loop.

Does this answer your question? isPrime Function for Python Language

What some people think: while using return inside a loop, they think that loop continues to iterate even after returning the value. But it is no so. The return statement gives the value and breaks the loop. for instance, As per your code while calling the function print(is_prime(15)), the output will be True. During iteration, it checks with the first value in the range(2,n) (i.e) 2.
It divides the 15 by the first number 2; Balance is not zero.So it returns True; The iteration stops. It doesn't check the other value in in the range(2,15)
But to find out whether a number is prime, It should be ensured whether n is not divisible by all the numbers in the given range. So, it can be written the other way around.
def is_prime(n):
    result = True
  
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            result = False; break
    return result
            

r = is_prime(15)
print(r) #Output: False

r = is_prime(17)
print(r) #Output: True

Here a default variable result is declared as True. Iteration is being done in the range(2,n). Now even if n is divisible even by one number, it returns False. If n is not divisible by all the numbers in the range, It returns the default value True

btw Your loop is very inefficient: After detecting that n is divisible by i, you set result = False and then go on to check the rest of the values of i. You may as well return False instead.

Thnk you. I've added a break now.

adhering to "single return" style may be mandated in some places. wherever it isn't, you can replace the result = False; break by a simple return False

@ChristophRackwitz, If you mention return False, the loop will continue to iterate though the answer is correct. For instance let us check is_prime(15); it starts wirh 2. There is a reminder. then 3. No reminder. so the result is turned False. As there is no break it'll check for 4,5,6,7.. also. Why to do that? It's an unwanted time waste right.?Even if a single number is divisible, stopping the loop will save the time.

I think you just confused yourself. please review what the return statement does in a function. then review my suggestion. you should understand why it's correct.

Is this what you mean?

I know it is possible, but my actual answer is easy to understand for people who are new.

Your current implementation of the is_prime function returns True for any number n that is greater than or equal to 2 but less than 1000, regardless of whether it is a prime number. This is due to the fact that the function simply determines if n is divisible by any number between 2 and n-1, returning True in the event that n is not.
You must modify the logic of your function in order to resolve the problem and correctly detect whether a given integer is prime. This is the updated version with run loop from 2 to square_root of n + 1
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

print(is_prime(975))  # This should print False
print(is_prime(2))    # This should print True


your claim about OP's code is incorrect: "... returns True for any number n that is greater than or equal to 2 but less than 1000, regardless of whether it is a prime number." because OP's code definitely does return False for some numbers in that range. you didn't see that the very first iteration returns in both cases, so the entire loop collapses to a simple test of divisor 2, and no others.

In your code in this part
for i in range(2,n):    LINE-1
    if(n%i==0):         LINE-2
         return False   LINE-3
    else:             
         return True

at LINE-2 it will be if(i%n==0) and NOT if(n%i==0)
The for loop will start from 2 and will go till (n-1) and dividing i by a number greater than it (for eg:2 % 975 = 0  ) will always give zero that's why you are getting "False" for 975
For 2 the for loop doesn't execute as the condition (staring_index < ending_index) is False
so it goes into the else condition to print "True"

format your question properly

you also misunderstood the code. -- Ivan means answer of course ;)
